# Grails: Ajax parameter is not reaching controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I had a button in my GSP that looked like this:

```
<button id = "select"
    onclick = "${remoteFunction(controller: 'customer', 
                                action: 'selectBatch',
                                params: '\'batchID=\' + selectedBatchID')}">
Select
</button>
```

All was well and the 'batchID' parameter was reaching my controller just fine, but I realized that I did not want to call this function everytime the button was clicked, only when some condition was met. So, I redefined my button like this:

```
<button id = "select" >Select</button>
```

and bounded it to a javascript function like this:

```
$('#select').click(function () {
    if (selectedBatchID == undefined) {
        $("#errorMessages p").text("Click a row to choose a batch first.");
        $("#errorMessages p").show();
        $("#errorMessages p").fadeOut(3000);
    }
    else {
        validBatchID = selectedBatchID;
        $("#choosebatch h2").text("Batch ID " + selectedBatchID + ": " + selectedBatchDesc);
        $('#AdminConsole p').css("font-size", "30px");
        $("#AdminConsole p").html("Batch ID " + selectedBatchID + "<br />" + selectedBatchDesc);
        console.log(selectedBatchID);
        $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: "${createLink(action:'selectBatch', controller:'customer')}/batchID=" + selectedBatchID
        });
    } 
});
```

Now it seems this variable isn't reaching my controller's functions which is like this:

```
def selectBatch = {
    println "Batch ID: " + params.batchID
    selectedBatch = Batch.findWhere(id: params.batchID.toInteger())
    println "Batch selected: " + selectedBatch
}
```

because my controller complains:

```
............Batch ID: null
Error |
2014-06-10 16:27:54,686 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  -         NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [POST] /FatcaOne_0/customer/selectBatch    /batchID=35
Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object
```

and this is what the Chrome debugger shows:

```
35 VM725:78
POST http://hostname/FatcaOne_0/customer/selectBatch/batchID=35 500 (Internal Server     Error) jquery.tools.min.js:38
send jquery.tools.min.js:38
f.extend.ajax jquery.tools.min.js:38
(anonymous function) VM725:79
f.event.dispatch jquery.tools.min.js:37
h.handle.i
```

So we can see that it isn't null because it prints the value '35' in the Chrome debugger but then why isn't the controller seeing this especially when it also gets included in the URI that is formed by the Ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your `$.ajax` with this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "${createLink(controller: 'customer', action: 'selectBatch')}",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {batchID: selectedBatchID}
});
```

Comment: This worked. If you would care to explain a little bit as to why this worked, I'd much appreciate it. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @AnonymousHuman when sending a HTTP POST request you don't append request parameters to the URL, instead they get passed in the body of the request. The way to do this when using `$.ajax` is to pass them as the value of the `data` property

Answer (score 1):

change '/' to '?':

```
${createLink(action:'selectBatch', controller:'customer')}/batchID=
```

to

```
${createLink(action:'selectBatch', controller:'customer')}?batchID=
```

If you are working with grails 2.x.x you could also write:

```
def selectBatch (Integer batchID) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this but got same result. Thanks for your suggestion. I do see that that might have been another approach but I'm still too new with Grails to understand the difference between '/' and '?'

Comment: add println params to see what you have